# Sort CSS files in Head

Tags: css, cms, head, file

I am developing a Magento 2.1.2 shop based on the Bootstrap library.
But the Bootstrap library should only get included in cms pages. So I added the following code in the file Magento_Cms/layout/cms_page_view.xml:

```
<head>
  <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" src_type="url" />
  <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url" />
</head>
```

The problem is, that the bootstrap CSS file gets included after the styles-l.css and styles-m.css files (shoud get included before).
So I did a bit of research in the web. The often recomended way to order files with the order="x" tag does not work.
This just does nothing:

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://domain.tld/static/_cache/merged/f20819a53f99bb909d9eb94305d9b4e9.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  order="3" href="http://domain.tld/static/frontend/[A]/[B]/de_DE/css/styles-m.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" order="4" href="http://domain.tld/static/frontend/[A]/[B]/de_DE/css/styles-l.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="print" href="http://domain.tld/static/frontend/[A]/[B]/de_DE/css/print.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  order="1" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  order="2" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
```

Like you can see, the order tag does not work., just like the "data-order" tag.

Does anyone know how to do that the right way?

It should just be like:

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://domain.tld/static/_cache/merged/f20819a53f99bb909d9eb94305d9b4e9.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  order="1" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  order="2" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  order="3" href="http://domain.tld/static/frontend/[A]/[B]/de_DE/css/styles-m.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" order="4" href="http://domain.tld/static/frontend/[A]/[B]/de_DE/css/styles-l.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="print" href="http://domain.tld/static/frontend/[A]/[B]/de_DE/css/print.css" />
```

Do nobody else have this problem? There have to be a way im Magento 2 to do that?

Comment: @RohitKundale no its not, because the solution there is not working in this Magento version.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the order in your `default_head_blocks.xml` is not in the way you want it.

There are different ways to inject CSS into Magento, one is to make usage of the above called file in `Vendor/Themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`.

Comment: I only want to include the files on cms pages.

Comment: On specific CMS pages, or on just one CMS page directly? There is an order that applies to those included files, first general styles get included and after that, sitespecific XML injections are done. So, what you can do is to extend `_extend.less` in your theme and specify it (.cms-home is a thing for example).

Comment: thank you for your answer. Do you know a possibility to inject a css file before the general styles?

Comment: You can just override existing CSS features as far as I know. You should do this, as its the most pleasent way to do so. Just copy the whole stylesheet after inspecting it and copy it to your modules _extend.less-File. It'll be then overridden - you can limit your query to specific pages. Don't forget to use less. Sorry if it didn't directly helped you, hopefully someone else can give you a better answer.